# How to write similar codes efficiently in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

Example 1:

```
- (NSString *)userToken
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userToken"];
}

- (void)setUserToken:(NSString *)userToken
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:userToken forKey:@"userToken"];
}

- (NSString *)userName
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
}

- (void)setUserName:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

These getter and setter are very similar. Is there a smart "macro" that can help me to simplify the codes? So I will be able to write few codes for each property like this:

```
XXXX(userToken)
XXXX(userName)
```

Example 2:

```
+ (MyManager *)sharedManager {
    // singleton
    ...
}

- (void)updateName:(NSString *)name {
    self.name = name;
}

+ (void)updateName:(NSString *)name {
    return [[self sharedManager] updateName:name];
}

- (void)updateUid:(NSString *)uid {
    self.uid = uid;
}

+ (void)updateUid:(NSString *)uid {
    return [[self sharedManager] updateUid:uid];
}
```

I want a way to write them efficiently, too.

What can I do?

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: @Wain
For example 1, I have tried to use macro. But macro cannot upper case the first letter automatically. So I have to write macros: XXXX(userName, UserName)
For example 2, I don't have any idea.